# Updating View After Data is Updated in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm working on an ASP.NET MVC app. I'm kind of new to ASP.NET MVC. I'm currently working on saving data. For that reason, I need to prepopulate a form if a record already exists. My controller currently looks like this:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int productId) 
{
  Product product = Product.FindById(productId);

  return View();
}
```

My view for this action looks like this:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <h3>Product</h3>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label" for="productName">Product Name</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="productName" name="productName" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I do NOT want to use the built-in HTML helpers. However, I am trying to figure out how to get the value of `product.Name` into the textbox named `productName`. How do I do this in MVC without using the HTML helpers?

Thank you!

Comment: not sure how you plan to show the product name since you don't pass the product to the view? If you don't want to use the helpers you could pass the product name directly in the value attribute of the input using the product which you could pass as model to the view...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would pass the product to the View so that the view so I could actually display the product details:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int productId) 
{
  Product product = Product.FindById(productId);

  return View(product);
}
```

and then in the View have something like:

```
@model Product

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <h3>Product</h3>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label" for="productName">Product Name</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="productName" name="productName" value="@Model.Name"  />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to transfer your `Product` into your view.
Therefore you need a ViewModel which can take your Product.
Then your View needs to know which ViewModel it will get.

Your modified controller action:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int productId) 
{
    Product product = Product.FindById(productId);

    EditViewModel viewModel = new EditViewModel( );
    viewModel.Product = product;

    return View( viewModel );
}
```

Your (maybe already existing) ViewModel:

```
public class EditViewModel
{
    public Product Product { get; set; }
}
```

Your modified view:

```
@model Your.Namespace.EditViewModel

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <h3>Product</h3>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label" for="productName">Product Name</label>
      <input type="text" value="@(Model.Product.Name)" class="form-control" id="productName" name="productName" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```